# Using Git repository on Virtualmin

Tags: git, cakephp, virtualmin

I have a VPS with CentOS 6.3 and Virtualmin on it. I have installed Virtualmin Git module according to [the official manual](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/git).

I created a new repository for a domain and it was placed in this location:
`/home/myproject/public_html/git/myproject.git`

According to the system, it can be accessed by using:
`git clone http://myuser@mydomain.com/git/myproject.git/`

When I run that command in my Git console, it asks for password alright. However, after that, it shows me an error and stops:

```
fatal: http://myuser@mydomain.com/git/myproject.git/info/refs not found:
did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I tried to simply open the repository URL in a web browser and it gives me a 404 on any subfolder under `git`, however, if I open just `/git`, it redirects me to `gitweb.cgi` and shows an internal server error. What might be causing this?

What am I missing to make this work? Basically I need my web app under `/public_html` to be in that repository. The app is based on CakePHP if that helps.

Comment: any solution to this so far? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you created user for that domain and tried replacing myuser with that username?